# What is the difference between Mat and SparseMat in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

What is the difference between Mat anf SparseMat in opencv?
when to use each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between `cv::Mat` and `cv::SparseMat` is the way they store data internally.

`cv::Mat` uses a *data array* closely related to a C data array (one in which the data is sequentially packed and addresses are directly computable from the indices of the element)

whereas,

`cv::SparseMat` uses a *hash table* to store just the nonzero elements. That hash table is maintained automatically, so when the number of (nonzero) elements in the array becomes too large for efficient lookup, the table grows automatically.

In simple terms,
`cv::Mat` class is used to represent dense arrays of any number of dimensions.
`cv::SparseMat` class is used when an array is likely to be very large compared to the number of nonzero entries.

- Both `cv:Mat` and `cv::SparseMat` are basic data structures in the C++ implementation of  OpenCV; with `cv::Mat` class being the largest implementation. Read more about them and other basic data structures in OpenCV [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html)
- Read more about basic image container in OpenCV [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html).